# ValueError: No closing quotation While building nativescript app

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing ios and android applications using native script-angular.When I created a new native script angular application and build that application it caused the error like

```
 File "./build-step-metadata-generator.py", line 40, in <module>
    header_search_paths_parsed = map_and_list((lambda s: "-I" + s), shlex.split(header_search_paths))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
    raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

How to fix the issue?

Comment: Probably the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS variable in your project is corrupted (unbalanced quotes). Can you verify its value?

You can add `printenv | sort` to your `platforms/ios/internal/nsld.sh` after `source ./.build_env_vars.sh` and build with `--log debug` to see it in the build output.

Comment: Ok i will try thanks for your response.

Comment: The file you have mentioned does not exist in the platforms/ios/internal/ folder.

Comment: nsld.sh is present from tns-ios@5.4.0 onwards. I guess you are using an earlier version. In this case you can add the same line to `platforms/ios/internal/nativescript-pre-build`

Comment: ok i will check.

Comment: My Header search paths value:HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS=/Users/admin/Documents/copied/MyNativeScriptPoc's/MyGraphPoc/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include  "/Users/admin/Documents/copied/MyNativeScriptPoc's/MyGraphPoc/platforms/ios/internal" "/Users/admin/Documents/copied/MyNativeScriptPoc's/MyGraphPoc/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/include" "/Users/admin/Documents/copied/MyNativeScriptPoc's/MyGraphPoc/platforms/ios/../../App_Resources/iOS/src" "/Users/admin/Documents/copied/MyNativeScriptPoc's/MyGraphPoc/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/src"

Comment: Are you using any specific plugins in your project? Can you post your `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the apostrophe in the path breaks ***shlex.split***. As a workaround I suggest that you rename the directory of your project to not have an ***'***